# Sdk for Dropbox, EverNote and Google Doc (WinRT)

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there any official Winrt SDK's are available for Dorpbox, EverNote and GoogleDoc. I searched for this in the internet but didn't find any working solutions. If anyone know more about this(Either official or 3rd party sdk's) Please share your thoughts with me.

Thanks in advance,

Stephan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropbox don't have WinRT api and probably it' wont change in near future, but you can also use REST Api:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api

So you can simply use this REST api because Windows 8/RT supports programing in  JavaScript and HTML:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br229565

EverNote and GoogleDoc should have some REST api too.