# Working Dropbox SDK for windows phone 8 & WInRT

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

Is there any working 3rd party sdk is available for windows phone 8 & WInRT, I tried with Higlabo,SharpDropBox etc. But all of these having issues with auth process. If anyone know how to authenticate Dropbox at least creation of signature please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551065/sdk-for-dropbox-evernote-and-google-doc-winrt

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox don't currently have an SDK for Windows Phone or Win RT.

They do have a a REST API (the best you'll get): https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api